# Is there a performance hit with simplifying a partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Let's say I have the following unsimplified column family:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  empID int,
  deptID int,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY ((empID, deptID)));
```

The partition key is both empID and deptID.

Under the assumption I will only search this table using both of these fields, can I simplify the table and rewrite is as following?

```
CREATE TABLE emp2 (
  empID_deptID text
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (empID_deptID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but I don't see any added value in doing it. In your first code example, Cassandra concatenates empID and deptID for you.

Comment: The reason I prefer to define it myself and not letting Cassandra do the concatenation for me is for allowing me to use the IN operator on all the partition key, rather than just the last partition key column only.

Answer (score 1):

In the precise example that you provided, there will be no difference. As a matter of fact, that is how it was done before composite partition keys became allowed in the previous versions.